# Resolving 404 not found when working on same page

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

In a Vue project, I mount a JSON file and it works with the URI. I use the data. I am trying to patch the data, but I cannot for the life of me resolve a 404 not found error when I try to patch the file in the handleCurrent function.

```
export default {
  name: "Home",

data() {
 return {
   entries: [],
   uri: "[CORRECT LINK]",
 };
},
mounted() {
fetch(this.uri)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => (this.entries = data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
},
methods: {


handleCurrent(id) {
  let currentCurrent = this.entries.filter((entry) => {
    return entry.label === "current";
  });

  currentCurrent.forEach((entry) => {
    entry.label = "none";
  });
 
  let newCurrent = this.entries.find((entry) => {
    return entry.id === id;
  });
  newCurrent.label = "current";

  fetch(this.uri, {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ deck: "current" }),
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
},
},
```

Comment: If the URL is the correct one then the error is probably on the server side that it does not accept a request with the method `PATCH` on that URL. While the server should report method not allowed in that case it might be that the sever side code is not implemented correctly.

Comment: There is a very similar function on a different component that is working. I'm new at this, but im lost right now

Comment: Most notably, the exact same URI is being mounted appropriately above the code at issue. You see they are both the same URI--the mounted hook works.

Comment: They have the same URI, but different access methods (one is `GET` and one is `PATCH`), due to that the outcome will be different. I agree that the response of `PATCH` should not be a `404` if GET does result in a `2xx`, and should be a 405 instead. But it could be that the server-side code is incorrect.